# Hibernate list mapping in a separate table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

We have two POJOs below

```
public class Notification extends AbstractDomainObject{

private String name;
private List<User> users;
//setter getter

}

public class User extends AbstractDomainObject{

private String userName;
//getter setter
}

public class AbstractDomainObject{
private Long id;
//getter setter

}
```

My Hibernate Mapping are

```
<hibernate-mapping >
    <class name="User" table="user">
        <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="userName" type="string">
            <column name="user_name" />
        </property>

    </class>

<class name="Notification " table="notification">
        <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>
        <list name="users" table="notification_for" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
   <key column="notification_id" />
   <list-index column="idx" />

   <one-to-many class="User" />
  </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want that hibernate should maintain a separate table(`notification_for`) for mapping of user and notification.

What hibernate is doing is maintaining `idx` and `notification_id` in `user`
 table. I want that hibernate should maintain a table `notification_for` with column `user_id` and `notification_id`  What should I do. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an many to many relationship:

On User side...

```
<bag name="notifications" inverse="true" table="NOTIFICATIONS_FOR">
  <key>
    <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Notification"/>
</bag>
```

Then on notifications side..

```
<bag name="users" inverse="false" table="NOTIFICATIONS_FOR">
      <key>
    <column name="notification_id" not-null="true"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Notification"/>
</bag>
```